# Error when reading SD formatted on Camera

Tags: mount, sd-card

Hello I have a 64GB microSD card (Samsung or Sandisk) and when I format it in the Ubuntu Laptop it works fine. When I use it in my Canon camera and I formatted so I can record when I try to mount it back to the Ubuntu it gives me the

> Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/angel/CANON: Command-line `mount -t
>   "exfat" -o
>   "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/angel/CANON"' exited with non-zero exit status 32:
>   mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'

and instead of use it again I have to reformat it.

The interesting part is that if I try to read it on a Windows machine (same laptop , dual boot) there is no error.

Also I tried an other sd card which works without problem both ubuntu and windows.

How can I fix the problem at Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that what is missing can be installed via terminal

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

It worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04. It is automounted like any external storage!

I found the answer [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/235655/how-to-mount-and-use-an-exfat-drive-on-linux/).

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: @Fabby You are tottaly right! Never thought about this! Chears

Comment: Good! answer now!  Upvoted!  **;-)**